# What is the correct Rails association for an events website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, model-associations

I need some advice on my rails event app, I can't figure out the correct association that I need in my models so I have broken it down for some guidance.

#### Speaker & Event Model

- An event has many speakers
- A speaker can belong to many events

#### Session, Speaker & Event Model

- An event has many sessions
- A session can belong to many events
- A session has one speaker
- A speaker can belong to many sessions

#### More info

The idea is that the event organiser can add speakers to an event and list them on the event show page and then closer to the event date, the event organiser builds the agenda using sessions. The agenda view has all the session information i.e. time, title as well as the speaker information that is associated to that session.

Comment: Last two seems like `Session belongs_to :speaker; Speaker has_many :sessions`. All the rest are either `has_and_belongs_to_many` or `has_many :through` depending on whether there is any more data connected with association.

Comment: "A session can belong to many events" : This doesn't make sense to me. A session should only belong to one event.

Comment: Why would a session belong to many events? isn't it a timely thing that happens in only one event?

Comment: Because after the event he finished it is duplicated ready for the next year and therefore the session is on 2 events until the new event has more up to date speakers. All past events are available to the public even once they have finished.

Comment: When you duplicate an event, you should duplicate the sessions also. Make a deep copy. It doesn't make sense to have the new even point to the session in the old event. If you then modify the session then the old session will also get modified.

Comment: And if you don't really care about the sessions then don't add sessions to the new event. Just keep the speakers and create sessions from scratch at your convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are planning to add speakers to an event first, and then later allow a moderator to organize them into sessions, I'd say you are very close to a working solution. Here's what I would recommend:

```
class Event
  has_many :events_speakers
  has_many :speakers, through: :events_speakers
  has_many :sessions
end

class Speaker
  has_many :events_speakers
  has_many :events, through: :events_speakers
  has_many :sessions_speakers
  has_many :sessions, through: :sessions_speakers
end

class Session
  # fields include: title, time
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :sessions_speakers
  has_many :speakers, through: :sessions_speakers
end
```

A few notes:

- I chose to allow a session to have many speakers to handle cases of panels or discussions
- A speaker has and belongs to many events to allow for easy adding of past speakers to new events or to show a speaker bio page with a list of events they have participated in.

If you know you'll never need either of those features, then you could simplify by removing the HABTM relationships.

One main change from your summary above is that I believe a Session should belong to only one Event. A session is an instance of a person/people speaking at a certain time, at a specific event, which is why it has a time attribute. If you need these sessions to repeat in the future, it makes sense to copy them to new session instances

Comment: Your explanation is exactly what I want but im getting a Mongoid Error - Problem:
  Invalid option :through provided to relation :speakers.
Summary:
  Mongoid checks the options that are passed to the relation macros to ensure that no ill side effects occur by letting something slip by.

Comment: Yeah mongoid handles 2 sided relationships a bit differently since it's a document store, not a relational db. you'll need to use this syntax: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#has_and_belongs_to_many but beware because it's pretty memory and space-intensive in mongo to store multi-sided relationships

Comment: so it would be has_and_belongs_to_many :speakers. plus side is, you don't need join tables :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to add a `Track` class (name it whatever you like, maybe `Subject` or `Category` are also suitable). A track is the abstraction of a session, a session has a time and speaker while a track is only about subject, so many session in many events (hence times) belong to single track.

I thinks this is the way to do it:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sessions
end

class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sessions
end

class Session < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :speaker
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :track
end

class Speaker < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sessions
end
```

All other associations that you've mentioned are actually *proxied* through these ones. So for "an event has many speakers" is actually "an event has many sessions each has a speaker", since a speaker wouldn't exist in an event if he doesn't speak in a session, right? That's why you shouldn't make a direct event - speaker relationship but rather proxy it through the event - session relationship.